# System.IO.FileStream is super slow on huge files

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code that needs to be able to modify a few bytes towards the end of a file. The problem is that the files are huge. Up to 100+ Gb.

I need the operation to be as fast as possible but after hours of Googeling, it looks like .Net is rather limited here???

I have mostly been trying using System.IO.FileStream and know of no other methods. A "reverse" filestream would do but I have know idea how to create one (write from the end instead of the beginning).

Here is sort of what I do: (Note: the time is spent when closing the stream)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        //Simulate a large file
        int size = 1000 * 1024 * 1024;
        string filename = "blah.dat";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        fs.SetLength(size);
        fs.Close();

        //Modify the last byte
        fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

        //If I don't seek, the modification happens instantly
        fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.WriteByte(255);

        //Now, since I am modifying the last byte, 
        //this last step is very slow
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: 100GB+ files? Use a database.

Comment: Yeah, they are media files and needs to be accessible on a fileshare. How would I use a database to modify the bytes on these?

Comment: BlueVoodoo: If you're concerned about performance now...DUDE! A 100GB file via a fileshare?! You're going about this wrong, methinks.

Comment: Also, what kind of speeds are you experiencing?

Comment: You're testing the creation of a *huge* file, not the speed of changing the last byte in such a file. Test on a file that already exists - and a file that isn't sparse (that is, a file with real data, not a file filled with zeroes)

Comment: @mattbasta: I don't know exactly. I have force quit on my 25 Gb test file when it stalls. I take your point with the fileshare, thanks.

@nos: yes, seems it's working fine if the file exists which is great but I'd love to get the sparse stuff working too. Ideally, I would like to be able to copy the header of the file before the data. (header data is available in the beginning and end of my files).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like Darin already noted, this is an artifact of your 'simulation' of a large file.

The delay is from actually 'filling up' the file, the delay only happens the first time. If you repeat the part from `//Modify the last byte` to `fs.Close();` it will be very fast.

Comment: The Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End) is what did it for me. Within a series of using statements for opening streams and readers, seeking to the end and allowing for GC to Dispose and terminate was lightning fast

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I've performed a few tests and results are a bit confusing. If you create the file and modify it in the same program it is slow:</strike>

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Simulate a large file
    int size = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
    string filename = "blah.datn";
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.SetLength(size);
    }

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.WriteByte(255);
    }
}
```

But if the file exists and you only try to modify the last byte it is fast:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = "blah.datn";
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
        fs.WriteByte(255);
    }
}
```

Hmmm...

---

UPDATE:

Please ignore my previous observations and **unmark this as an answer because it is all wrong**.

Further investigating the issue I've noticed the following pattern. Suppose that you allocate a file of given size with zero bytes like this:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("blah.dat"))
{
    stream.SetLength(100 * 1024 * 1024);
}
```

This operation is very fast and it creates a 100MB file filled with zeros.

Now if in some other program you try to modify the last byte, closing the stream will be slow:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite("blah.dat"))
{
    stream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
    stream.WriteByte(255);
}
```

I have no idea of the internal workings of the file system or how exactly is this file created but I have the feeling that it is not completely initialized until you try to modify it and closing the handle will be slow.

To confirm this I tested in unmanaged code (feel free to fix any aberration as my C is very rusty):

```
void main()
{
    int size = 100 * 1024 * 1024 - 1;
    FILE *handle = fopen("blah.dat", "wb");
    if (handle != NULL) {
        fseek(handle, size, SEEK_SET);
        char buffer[] = {0};
        fwrite(buffer, 1, 1, handle);
        fclose(handle);
    }
}
```

This behaves the same way as in .NET => it allocates a file of 100MB filled with zeros and it is very fast.

Now when I try to modify the last byte of this file:

```
void main()
{
    int size = 100 * 1024 * 1024 - 1;
    FILE *handle = fopen("blah.datn", "rb+");
    if (handle != NULL) {
        fseek(handle, -1, SEEK_END);
        char buffer[] = {255};
        fwrite(buffer, 1, 1, handle);
        fclose(handle);
    }
}
```

The last `fclose(handle)` is slow. I hope some experts will bring some light here.

It seems though that modifying the last byte of a real file (not sparse) using the previous methods is very fast.

Comment: Hmmm... That is interesting indeed. Got the same result. Seens odd to work around by closing the app and open it again.

Comment: Indeed it is very strange. As in your case the file exists and you only want to modify at the end it should be OK but I would be interested in finding the reason for this.

Comment: It's not so strange, `fs.SetLength(newBigSize)` is very fast because it cheats a little. Note that results will vary between NTFS and FATnn filesystems.

Comment: I'm still confused; my Linux ext3 system was able to create a sparse 512 GB file in under .002 seconds. Is BlueVoodoo's slowness due to using the incorrect API for creating sparse files? (e.g., does FileStream actually write out a bunch of zero blocks for a sparse file?) Or is NT generally this slow when creating sparse files?

Comment: So, there is still something odd going on here. Just tried the exact same code but instead of using: string filename = "blah.dat"; I used string filename = @"d:\blah.dat" (so... not c:\ where the windows virtual mem is) Now, it is all slow again. :( 

c: and d: are two different NTFS partitions on my internal laptop HD.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo, I've tried the same as you did (storing the file on a different partition) and unless you create and modify the file in the same program it was fast for me. I am afraid that an insight from the gurus will be needed here :-)

Comment: @Darin Yes, sorry. You are right. The issue is still related to the simulated file. If I create it, stop the application, run the second part of your code, it's still slow. If I stop the application again and run the second part of the code another time without changing the code at all, it's fast. Seems some background process requires it to complete the writing.

Comment: @BlueVodoo, using a non-sparse real world file is fast.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the fastest way to work with large files in using a [MemoryMappedFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx). A memory-mapped file is a file that is mapped (not loaded) into virtual memory so you can access random bytes in it without having to seek to a specific location, load buffers etc.  You can also read entire structures directly from the file without going through deserialization.

The following code, coming straight out of MSDN, loads and stores a MyColor structure in the middle of a 512MB file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long offset = 0x10000000; // 256 megabytes
    long length = 0x20000000; // 512 megabytes

    // Create a memory-mapped view of a portion of 
    // an extremely large image, from the 256th megabyte (the offset)
    // to the 768th megabyte (the offset plus length).
    using (var mmf = 
        MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\ExtremelyLargeImage.data",
                                                    FileMode.Open,"ImgA"))
    {
        using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
        {

            int colorSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyColor));
            MyColor color;

            // Make changes to the view.
            for (long i = 0; i < length; i += colorSize)
            {
                accessor.Read(i, out color);
                color.Brighten(10);
                accessor.Write(i, ref color);
            }
        }
    }

}

public struct MyColor
{
    public short Red;
    public short Green;
    public short Blue;
    public short Alpha;

    // Make the view brigher.
    public void Brighten(short value)
    {
        Red = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Red + value);
        Green = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Green + value);
        Blue = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Blue + value);
        Alpha = (short)Math.Min(short.MaxValue, (int)Alpha + value);
    }
}
```

You can find more info and samples at [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I have read about this method on msdn. I am on v3.5 at the moment and not able to test my piece of code using the memory mapping. If it works, I'd be happy to get v4.0.

Comment: You can already use Memory Mapped files using the unmanaged Windows API. Just makes the pain vs gain factor a bit higher

Comment: Memory-mapped files are still paged-in-and-out of memory/disk by the OS, so theoretically overall throughout performance should be the same - except the problem with memory-mapped files is that you now have blocking IO in your thread and the potential for all-kinds of side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try it with a real file rather than a "simulated" file.
It may be that .net is using some sparse allocation mechanism and only writes out the file up to the last byte actually written to.

So, when you write to the beginning of the file it only has to write out a few bytes, but when you write to the end of the file it actually has to write out the whole file.